# In python django, would it be possible to extract data from database table and store it in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, django, django-models, web-development-server

I tried to extract the data using 'tablename.objects.Fname()' but I am still confused on how to store all the first names in the array from database.

if yes could anyone provide with an example, any sort of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't use an array, use a `ForeignKey` to define many-to-one relation.

Comment: (Aside: Python's [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html?highlight=array#module-array) probably isn't what you meant. Maybe a `list`? In any case, Willem's comment about `ForeignKeys` is correct.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the values stored in a column by using [**`.values(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values), or [**`.values_list(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list). For example:

```
tablename.objects.values_list('Fname', flat=True)
```

This `QuerySet` is an iterable that for each record will contain one element with the cleaned value of that record. So if it is an `ArrayField`, it will contain a collection of lists.

But using an [**`ArrayField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) or other composite field is often *not* a good idea. It makes the items in the array harder to process, filter, JOIN, etc. Therefore it is often better to make an extra table, and define a many-to-one relation, for example with a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey).